# Maven: Repositories in settings.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have following `.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>

        <repository>
          <id>jboss-ga-repository</id>
          <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>

      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
          <id>jboss-ga-plugin-repository</id>
          <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

When I try run `mvn install` against my project it says:

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:6.4.0.GA' in repository central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools

Reason: POM 'org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:6.4.0.GA

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools
```

But it tried only `central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`. Why did it ignore repositories specified in `settings.xml`?

Comment: You have configured it into a profile and didn't activate that profile and not given it an id...

Comment: I would recomment to install a repository manager and handle that in the repository manager instead in the settings.xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles need to be activated in your Maven build. There are several ways to activate them (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). For example, you can activate it at the command line using:

```
mvn ... -Pprofile-1
```

But obviously you'll need to declare the profile ID in the `<profile>` node that you showed.